# Obtaining results from fields using getattr() with differing field types in Django

Tags: python, django

My models use a mix of `charfields`, `ManyToManyFields` and the issue is how best to return the field given that some fields have different values. For example, with the `Charfields` I can employ `.__str()__` but this only works with single value fields. However the `ManyToManyFields` will store a whole series of options which means that `.__str()__` doesn't relate to the stored values and values, but can be accessed with `.values_list()`.

The reason I need to do this is that I have a list of field names that I am looping over, one at a time and calling the Model via:

```
mylist = ["fieldA", "fieldB", "fieldC"]

MyModel = Model.objects.get(pk=ID)
```

and then

```
field_in_list = mylist[i]
getattr(MyModel, field_in_list)
```

so I'd like to be able to pull field values without needing to know what type of field it is in advance. Is there a generic method that will enable me to do this?

Comment: Maybe it would help to think through further what actual result you want. Because `getattr(MyModel, field_in_list)` already does literally what you asked for _"pull field values without needing to know what type of field it is in advance"_

Comment: @Anentropic getattr(..,ManyToManyFields) behaves very differently to getattr(..,Charfield), The former does not give me any values at all and points to the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you want a special case to handle relation fields which give you a model manager, and you want a list of all the related instances:

```
from django.db import models

field_names = ["fieldA", "fieldB", "fieldC"]
instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=ID)

values = []
for field_name in field_names:
    value = getattr(instance, field_name)
    if isinstance(value, models.Manager):
        values.append(value.all())
    else:
        values.append(value)

['valueA', 'valueB', [<RelatedModel pk=1>, <RelatedModel pk=3>]]
```